# Is it possible to see a snapshot of all the memory allocations made by a particular process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory, process, malloc

The important data I want about these allocations is the function pointer value which did these mallocs. Otherwise I know of pmap and /proc/[pid]/maps. Both these techniques lack the function pointers of the functions that did the malloc. Thanks!

Comment: SuperUser might be a better place for this.

Comment: Well, `address sanitizer` keeps track of who allocated what, so it's definitely possible, but it *does*  keep a lot of metadata for that purpose.

Comment: This isn't tracked, in general (because it serves no useful purpose, in general).  Something like Valgrind might track this, though.

Comment: The closest you can reasonably easy obtain is the return address, which generally is **inside** the calling function.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - I think Valgrind's `Massif` heap profiler in particular will do this...a quick excerpt from [its website](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.thesnapshotdetails) has this line: "...As well as the basic counts, it gives an allocation tree which indicates exactly which pieces of code were responsible for allocating heap memory..."